# Extracting the file version from the file name

Tags: regex, perl

I have the file names as below:

```
first_config.txt.1.1
second_config.2.1.1.1
```

I wanted to separate file name & version from the complete file name using perl.

```
first_config.txt & 1.1 
second_config & 2.1.1.1
```

I tried the below code, but its not working as expected.

```
to extract the version from the complete file name string:
perl -e '$n = "first_config.txt.1.1"; $n =~s/[^\.\d.]//g; print "$n\n";'

to extract the name from the complete file name string:
perl -e '$n = "first_config.txt.1.1"; $n =~s/[\.^\d.]//g; print "$n\n";'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a regular expression to extract digits and `.` from the end of the string:

```
my ($name, $version) = $filename =~ /(.*?)\.([.\d]*)$/;
```

Answer (score 3):

Split into 2 on a `.` followed by a digit:

```
my ($name, $version) = split /\.(?=\d)/, $filename, 2;
```